# Gradle build by selecting *Test.java files

Tags: android, gradle, junit

My app is being tested by junit, robolectric and gradle build.

The test code follows below structure.
`approot/mytest/com/xx/pkg/*.java`

```
   test {                                                               
         java {  
               srcDir 'mytest'
              }
   }
```

This includes all the files under test pakage, needlessly including some of the utility files.

I have all the test files name `xxxxxTest.java`, `yyyyTest.java` etc.
So I thought to change `srcDir` to `mytest/**/*Test.java` or `/mytest/com/xx/pkg/*Test.java`, build does not compile any test code. However `/mytest/com/xx/pkg/*.java` picks all test source files.

Any pointers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TestFilter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html) to achieve this. Try the following:

```
test {
    filter {
       includeTestsMatching "*Test"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats it.Thanks alot.

Comment: @jsam In that case, would you consider accepting the answer? :)

Comment: Accepted. Looks like my reputation is too low to give you a rating

Comment: @jsam Don't worry about upvoting. Accepting an answer sends a clear signal that your issue has been solved by the answer. Upvoting is just to show that given answer is of\ high quality. Sometimes only one applies.